# Attempting to DM an author after a given command

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to figure out how to initiate a Direct Message between player and bot through commands. The command should work such that the player DM's the bot with !stats, and three numbers (Example: !stats 6 8 1) and the bot will respond with the appropriate allocation of stats. (Example: You have put 6 points in Strength, 8 points in Dexterity, and 1 point on Constitution.)

The following code I have is such:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import json
from pathlib import Path

class Character(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Bot is Online")

    @commands.command()
    async def name(self, ctx, name):

        player = str(ctx.message.author)
        path = os.getcwd()
        charFolder = os.path.join(path + "/characters/")
        charFile = Path(charFolder + player + ".txt")

        # Get the name of character being created
        if charFile.is_file():
            await ctx.send("You've already created a character, dumbass.")
        else:
            await ctx.send("I did it!")
            await ctx.send("Your character name is: " + name)
            await ctx.send("Your character sheet has been created.")
            levelDict = {1: [25, 1, 6, 15, 2, 1, 5, 75]}
            characterFile = {}
            level = 1
            xp = 0
            characterFile["name"] = name
            characterFile["level"] = level
            hp = levelDict[1][0]
            characterFile["hp"] = hp
            tFeats = levelDict[1][4]
            characterFile["total feats"] = tFeats
            numberOfDice = levelDict[1][1]
            numberOfSides = levelDict[1][2]
            characterFile["base damage"] = str(numberOfDice) + "d" + str(numberOfSides)
            characterFile["hit"] = levelDict[1][5]
            characterFile["damage"] = levelDict[1][5]
            characterFile["ac"] = levelDict[1][6]
            characterFile["currentxp"] = xp
            nextLevel = levelDict[1][7]
            characterFile["nextlevel"] = nextLevel
            characterFile["strength"] = 0
            characterFile["dexterity"] = 0
            characterFile["constitution"] = 0
            characterFile["remaining feats"] = 2
            ap = levelDict[1][3]
            characterFile["total ap"] = ap
            hasTaken = []
            characterFile["feats taken"] = hasTaken
            file = open(charFolder + player + ".txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
            json.dump(characterFile, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
            await ctx.send("PM me with '!stats <str> <dex> <con>' to set your abilities. Wouldn't want everyone "
                     "to see your secrets, would we?")

    @commands.command()
    async def stats(self, ctx, strength, dexterity, constitution):

        private = self.client.send_message
        player = str(ctx.message.author)
        path = os.getcwd()
        charFolder = os.path.join(path + "/characters/")
        charFile = Path(charFolder + player + ".txt")
        if not charFile.is_file():
            await private(player,  "You don't even have a character created yet. Type !name <name> in the room. "
                                   "Where <name> is your character's actual name. (Example: !name Joe")

        else:
            strMod = int(int(strength) / 2)
            dexMod = int(int(dexterity) / 2)
            conMod = int(int(constitution) * 5)
            print(strMod, dexMod, conMod)
            await private(player, "Allocating the following: \n\n"
                                   "Strength: " + strength + "   (+" + str(strMod) + " bonus to hit and damage.)\n"
                                   "Dexterity: " + dexterity + "   (+" + str(dexMod) + " bonus to armor class.)\n"
                                   "Constitution: " + constitution + "   (+" + str(conMod) + " bonus to armor class.)\n")
```

BotCommands.py

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

token = open("token.txt", "r").read()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension("cogs." + extension)

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension("cogs." + extension)

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension("cogs." + filename[:-3])

client.run(token)
```

This returns error:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'

Do I need to initiate some 'on_message' command in BotCommands.py? Or am I just calling the method wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```py
# BotCommands.py
...
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
...

# code.py
...
    @commands.command()
    async def stats(self, ctx, strength, dexterity, constitution):
        private = self.client.send_message # <--
        ...
```

the discord api has changed

from https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?#sending-messages

---

## Sending Messages

One of the changes that were done was the merger of the previous Client.send_message and Client.send_file functionality into a single method, send().

Basically:

```py
# before
await client.send_message(channel, 'Hello')

# after
await channel.send('Hello')
```

Comment: Ahhh. I clearly wasn't more thorough on my documentation research. Thanks